# Bridges / Mesh smoothing

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm trying to sculpt this hand and I came up with this extrude big thumb but when I create a bridge to smooth it out, it gets like that. How can I fix it? If I 'subdivision surface' it gets weirder... :/

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: please don't ask twice the same question, I answered your first question, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on “dyntopo” (dynamic topology) on the top menu setting if it’s what you call it (but you can also hit ctrl + d). Then, you can start to fix those “weird” stuff, Haha. The tool adds more vertices when you need to make something detail. Custom data won’t be preserved, however.